# Extension method is not visible

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I am thinking to create some [Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) for the thing below.

[image]

So I plan to see

```
 @item.Roles.ConvertToString(...
```

I created also the extancion method itself. But It is not appearing in place I need.

```
 @item.Roles.  Nothing what I need... :(
```

Any clue?

**P.S.**

```
 public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string ConvertToString(this ICollection<IdentityUserRole> identityUserRole)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your extension method.

Comment: Have you added a reference to your class in web.config or at the top of the view?

Comment: Where does `MyExtensions` live in relation to your model class?

Comment: have included the namespace in  your file

Comment: Is your extension method located in the same namespace? If not you need to include it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the namespace containing your extension method using the `@using` directive.

Comment: Alternatively you can add an entry under `<pages> <namespaces>` in the top web.config. Sample entry would look like this: `<add namespace="Mydomain.Extensions" />`.

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods aren't usable if you haven't imported the namespace their class is defined in.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to export the namespace of that extension method

```
     @using WhereeverTheNameSpaceIs
```

Does it show up then?